# How to encode for YouTube with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, youtube

I just read [Recommended upload encoding settings](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171?hl=en) article from official google support. I think this is the best settings for encoding my youtube videos.

Can you help me find out how to encode that settings in ffmpeg for 720p or 1080p videos?

**Here's the settings**

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf yadif,format=yuv420p -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced/2)" -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -bf 2 -c:a aac -q:a 1 -ac 2 -ar 48000 -use_editlist 0 -movflags +faststart out.mp4
```

`-vf` specifies video filters

`yadif` will deinterlace videos if they're interlaced.

`format=yuv420p` will produce pixel format with 4:2:0 chroma subsampling.

`-force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced/2)"` will place keyframes every half-second, so that will be the GOP size.

`-c:v libx264` will use the x264 encoder to produce a H264 video stream.

`-crf 18` will produce a visually lossless file. Better than setting  a bitrate manually.

`-bf 2` will limit consecutive B-frames to 2

`-c:a aac` will use the native encoder to produce an AAC audio stream.

`-q:a 1` sets the highest quality for the audio. Better than setting  a bitrate manually.

`-ac 2` rematrixes audio to stereo.

`-ar 48000` resamples audio to 48000 Hz.

`-use_editlist 0` avoids writing edit lists.

`-movflags +faststart` places moov atom/box at front of the output file.

Comment: I believe you wrote this answer using this [Recommended Upload Settings](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171) as reference. Here's the command for [Content ID Partners](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6039860): `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf yadif,format=yuv422p -force_key_frames expr:gte(t\,n_forced/2) -c:v libx264 -b:v <60M for 1080, 50M for 720, 15M for SD> -bf 2 -c:a flac -ac 2 -ar 44100 -use_editlist 0 -movflags +faststart out.mp4`.

Comment: Any idea how I can run this on fish shell where parentheses `(t\,n_forced/2)` are interpreted as a command?

Comment: Enclose `expr:gte(t\,n_forced/2)` in single or double quotes, I guess

Comment: -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced/2)"

Comment: @MCCCS could you give a rundown of the differences?

Comment: @Zoom Content ID Partners can (and should) use 44.1kHZ and the lossless audio codec PCM-FLAC (note: I forgot to add 16 or 24 bits audio to my command). They should use higher bitrates for video. They should use 4:2:2 not 4:2:0. Note that my command is untested.

Comment: @Gyan Is there any difference between in your answer `-force_key_frames expr:gte(t\,n_forced/2)` and `-g <framerate/2>`?